# Error with Dictionary Object: The name 'LotMaterialList' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I have a Dictionary Object declared as such:

```
Dictionary<string, string> LotMaterialList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

I'm later populating a combobox as such:

```
cbxMaterials.ItemsSource = LotMaterialList;
cbxMaterials.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
cbxMaterials.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
```

This is working fine. I have it in a popup on a panel and showing all the information correctly. On the Selection Change for the combobox I have this code:

```
if (null != cbxMaterials.SelectedValue)  
{  
  CreateEditMaterial.materialId = cbxMaterials.SelectedValue.ToString();  
  CreateEditMaterial.materialDesc = LotMaterialList(CreateEditMaterial.materialId);  
}
```

And the LotMaterialList is giving me the error of `The name 'LotMaterialList' does not exist in the current context` I have done this before without issues, compared how I did it then to this and I can't spot any differences. So I'm guessing I'm missing something really simple.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Where is `LotMaterialList` declared? Can you post your full code?

Comment: This doesn't look right: `= LotMaterialList(CreateEditMaterial.materialId);`.  Did you mean to have it in brackets, like so? `= LotMaterialList[CreateEditMaterial.materialId];`

Comment: @Gjeltema Yes, something simple as I said... If coding for long hours, more coffee is needed. Thanks it is working now.

Comment: Cool - posted as an answer so this question can be closed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `()` instead of `[]` to access your `Dictionary`.

Replace:

```
CreateEditMaterial.materialDesc = LotMaterialList(CreateEditMaterial.materialId);
```

with

```
CreateEditMaterial.materialDesc = LotMaterialList[CreateEditMaterial.materialId];
```